# jquery auto print the row number

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've a table with 10 row, is it possible to print the row number (from 1 to 9, the first row is NO&title, the second row should be 1) to the td with class "sno" based on the size of the table? here is the html:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="23%">No.</td>
    <td width="77%">Title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

the result should be

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="23%">No.</td>
    <td width="77%">Title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">1</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">2</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">3</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">4</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">5</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">6</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">7</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">8</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">9</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

The question is not generate the table, it is print the right number to target

Comment: size of table means? Do you want print numbers of all `.sno` ? Here `.sno` contains only blank spaces not numbers.

Comment: size of the table is 10

Comment: This is incredibly easy to do in both vanilla JavaScript and jQuery .. what have you tried?

Comment: @hkinterview have you seen answer below ? There is solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/3BBEN/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //use a special class name or id for the table
    //using find I'm getting all tr elements in the table
    //using not(':eq(0)') I'm ignoring the first tr element
    //using each I'm iterating through the selected elements
    $('table').find('tr').not(':eq(0)').each(function(i){
        //using children('td:eq(0)') I'm getting the first td element inside the tr
        $(this).children('td:eq(0)').addClass('sno').text(i+1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the simpleone

```
$('table tbody tr').not(":first").each(function(idx){
     $(this).children(":eq(0)").html(idx + 1);
});
```

Comment: you missed that `:first` otherwise, it will replace the heading `No.` also. http://jsfiddle.net/ShnLw/

Answer (score 1):

try this::

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;

    $('.sno').each(function(){
        $(this).text(i);
        i++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $cells=$("table td.sno");
    for(var i=0;i<$cells.length;i++)
    {
        //  alert(i);
        $cells.eq(i).text(i);
    }
});
```

Check on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qcWec/1/

Comment: That is very inefficient, you get the `$("table td.sno")` object twice on every loop.

Comment: Better, but you should only get the `$(…)` object once, then iterate over it so do something like `var $cells = $("table td.sno");`, then `…;i < $cells.length;…` and `$cells[i].text(i)` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Table row elements have a rowIndex property that is the zero–based sequence number for the table

section that they are in. So if you have a reference to a cell you can use:

```
var rowIndex = cell.parentNode.rowIndex;
```

If you have header rows in a table, you probably should put them in a thead table section, then

you can number the rows in tbody section easily, e.g.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>head<td>head
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="sno"></td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sno"></td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So now you can do something like:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
  var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;

  for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = i + 1;
  }
};
```

Of course you can get the rows some other way (e.g. class), but the above is independent of that.